# Create a partial curved line in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
icc <- function(b, a, c) {
    if (missing(c)) c <- 0
    if (missing(a)) a <- 1
    theta <- seq(-3, 3, .1)
    P <- c + (1 - c) / (1 + exp(-a * (theta - b)))
    df<- data.frame(theta,P)
    ggplot(df,aes(theta,P))+
    geom_smooth()+
    geom_point()
}

icc(1)
```

I have this function that creates a curved line using geom_smooth() and geom_point(). However, I want to break this curve like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2yHZ.jpg).

Comment: Try [`geom_segment()`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_segment.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subset the `df` created in the function.

```
library(ggplot2)

icc <- function(b, a, c) {
    if (missing(c)) c <- 0
    if (missing(a)) a <- 1
    theta <- seq(-3, 3, .1)
    P <- c + (1 - c) / (1 + exp(-a * (theta - b)))
    df<- data.frame(theta,P)
    ggplot(subset(df, theta < b), aes(theta,P))+
    geom_smooth()+
    geom_point()+
    xlim(-3, 3) +
    ylim(0, 1)
}

icc(1)
```

Comment: The y axis only shows up till  0.5. I want it to show up from 0-1

Comment: @ujjwaltyagi Included `ylim(0, 1)`, see now.